# useEffect hook depend on object/array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

useEffect working pretty well with primitives, but then I need it to run when array value changes, e.g. I have props.items, then I load items but some ids are different. I tried to use it like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
}, [...props.items.map((i) => i.id)])
```

but this solution throws error from react, saying dependency array must not change between calls.
Anyone managed to find solid workaround for this situation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"I need it to run when array value changes"* `[props.items]` should work if you update the array correctly (i.e. create a new instance when you add,remove or change items). If you are not doing that then you should do it.

Comment: You don't need to map inside the dependency array. `useEffect(() => {
}, [props.items])`  should be fine. The `props.items` don't need to be an array as well. If the reference of `props.items` changes, the hook will be triggered.

Comment: Thanks @FelixKling and Vishnu for clarification. It was bugging me for quite some time.

Comment: Also, with @FelixKling approach, you're preventing a map over the items when it's not necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// don't
useEffect(() => {
}, [...props.items.map((i) => i.id)]) // this makes new array with spread operator (...), and then returns another one with .map method

// do
useEffect(() => {
}, [props.items]) // this just points to an existing array we want to watch for changes
```